# Как добавить мини картинку на кнопку в Телеграм боте на java?

Tags: java, telegrambots

Всем привет, подскажите как можно добавить изображения на кнопки в телеграм боте на java?
Сейчас кнопки создаются так как на скрине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинки на кнопки в Телеграм ставить невозможно. Можете изучить телеграмм-боты других компаний, сообществ и так далее. Можно добавить "эмодзи", для этого нужно использовать просто специальный код.
Нужна эта зависимость:

```java
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

И вот такой кусок кода, делайте под себя:

```
public enum Icon {
    PLUS(":heavy_plus_sign:"),
    MINUS(":heavy_minus_sign:"),
    CHECK(":white_check_mark:"),
    NOT(":x:"),
    DOUBT(":zzz:"),
    FLAG(":checkered_flag:")

    private String value;

    public String get() {
        return EmojiParser.parseToUnicode(value);
    }

    Icon(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Источник: [ССЫЛКА](https://habr.com/ru/post/482260/)